# Using setTermCriteria of cv2 and svm

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, image-processing, svm

I am trying to use setTermCriteria with SVM. But when I use it I am getting below error:

```
AttributeError: 'cv2.ml_SVM' object has no attribute 'setTermCritera_MAX_ITER'
```

This is how I am using it

```
svm.setTermCritera_MAX_ITER=10000
svm.setTermCriteria_EPS = 1e-3
```

I am not getting error but not finding it useful when I use it below way:

```
cv2.setTermCritera_MAX_ITER=10000
cv2.setTermCriteria_EPS = 1e-3
```

When I try below method

```
svm.setTermCriteria(10000)
SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple
```

Which is the right way to use it in Python with OpenCV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is clear, a tuple is needed. Let's see the default value:

```
svm = cv2.ml.SVM_create()
svm.getTermCriteria()
```

returns `(3, 1000, 1.1920928955078125e-07)`. So if you want to set only the maximum number of iterations should call:

```
svm.setTermCriteria((cv2.TermCriteria_MAX_ITER, 10000, 0))
```

and if want to keep the same epsilon criterion and also set max iter:

```
svm.setTermCriteria((cv2.TermCriteria_MAX_ITER + cv2.TermCriteria_EPS, 10000, 1.1920928955078125e-07))
```